# Strange behavior in Gmail IMAP server while trying to open folder with spaces at the end of folder name

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

Using javamail 1.4.5. 
Connected to the gmail imap server and getting list of all folders.
Getting one folder with name "YO/comms " (last space is in the name), while trying to get type of the folder getting exception "javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: YO/comms  not found"
After getting sub folder of it called "YO/comms / social media" and it's working fine on opening and getting all the messages from it.

May be you can suggest what could be a problem there ? 
Trace on this returns:
A7 LIST "" "YO/comms "
A7 OK Success

Thanks

Comment: As we discussed privately, this looks like a Gmail bug, but let's see if anyone else has any information...

Comment: I posted this question here hoping that someone from Gmail team can provide the answer.